# Difference between key and index in arrays

Tags: arrays, indexing, key, tcl

I'm confused with the terms `index`, `key` , `key-value pair`  & `element` with respect to arrays in TCL or say any other programming language in general.

I know that we use `index` for non-associative arrays and keys for associative arrays , but don't understand why.

Can anyone help me understand the exact meaning (difference between them) and usage of these terms.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An `index` is typically numeric (it's an integer, starting at zero and increasing to number of elements minus one). It identifies the element of interest by its *ordinal* position in the array.

A `key` is typically a string or object. It identifies an element in the array "by name."

An `element` is just an item in an array.

Keys are used for "associative arrays" because you are "associating" a key with a value.  A `key-value pair` is simply an object that contains both a key and the value associated with that key.

#### (Advanced)

How you use keys and indices has performance implications.  If an "associative array" is implemented with a hash table, its performance is `O(1)`.  If it's implemented with a binary tree, it is `O(n log n)`

Accessing an array by its index is always `O(1)` because finding the correct element is essentially an arithmetic problem.  Finding an item in an array if you have neither an index nor a key is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology can be a little confusing.  What Tcl calls an `array` is always an associative array (implemented as a hash table), even if the keys happen to be numeric.  Tcl `list`s are more like other languages' arrays.  You read the value at position n in list l with `lindex l n`, where n is numeric (but a few other forms, like `end` are supported).  As Robert Harvey points out this is a constant-time operation.